# how to write argotic.feed.save result into memory stream?

Tags: c#, stream, argotic

I want to write [Argotic](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) to memorystream and then return it as a string to another function.
and this is what I've written :

```
            Stream st = new MemoryStream();
            Feed.Save(st); //argotic Save method has the ability to write into Stream
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

but I only got an empty string although the st.length shows me the correct length but there no character in it :-?

how Can I solve this problem?

regards.

Comment: When working with streams you should get familiar with the `using` statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I'm totally familiar with how to use "using" the above snippet is for the sake of giving an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset the position of the stream to 0 to read from the beginning, after the save. Otherwise you'll read from the current position, which is the end of the stream since it has just been written to:

```
st.Position = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I've changed my code to something like : int i = st.Read(b, 0, (int)st.Length); and then convert byte to string and now its working :)